# layer-backed NSViews overlapping / order

Tags: macos, cocoa, calayer, nsview

I set up two NSViews (a toolbar which overlaps view1) with the help of the interface builder / auto layout and then in -(void)awakeFromNib I call

```
[self.view1 setWantsLayer:YES];
[self.toolbar setWantsLayer:YES];
```

to make the views layer-backed so I can animate them later on. I found out that if I call setWantsLayer on the toolbar after I call it on view1 it gets displayed over view1 not caring about the order in the interface builder. So far, so good.

My question is: how can I change the order of the views later on in code. Calling

```
self.toolbar.zPosition = 0;
self.view1.zPosition = 1;
```

doesn't do anything. Since I'm feeling not so confident with CALayers:
Is there something I'm missing?
And is there a good tutorial for CALayers - I read the docs, but didn't understand everything (concept of layer-hosting views, sublayers, ...)

## edit

an image for better understanding (I want to animate the transparency of the green view so the black toolbar is over the red view and the green view is gone. and back to green view):
[image: views overlapping]

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the second view relative to the first using `addSubview:positioned:relativeTo:`. The layer index is relative only to that layers in the parent layer, not the view hierarchy its self.

For example,

```
[hostingView addSubview:topView
        positioned:NSWindowAbove
        relativeTo:bottomView];
```

Comment: thank you for your response. I tried to addSubview:self.toolbar ... but I can't see any difference. Isn't it the case that CALayers are always visible in front of NSViews?

Comment: Seriously though this should work... If you want help still add some details, code and maybe an image.